# How can I change the height of some child widgets according to index in Gridview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview

Exactly what I'm trying to do is that the 0th and 1st index widgets have a height of 200 and other indexes have a height of 50

```
GridView.builder(
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  gridDelegate:
                      const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                  ),
                  itemCount: pageData.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    }
                       

                    if (index == 0 || index == 1) {
                      return 
                        child: CustomFrameGroup(
                          height: 200, 
                          onTap: () {},
                        );
                    
                    } else {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                        child: CustomFrameGroup(
                          height: 50, 
                          color: Colors.teal.withOpacity(opacityValue),
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },

                )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXiYp.png)

Answer (score 0):

The height of item in a GridView's SliverGridDelegate depends on mainAxisExtent as a fixed value.

If the mainAxisExtent is null, childAsectRatio is used instead.

It's a fixed value, and it applies to all child.

So, if you want to use dynamic height, you should use flutter_staggered_grid_view.

See the pacakges on https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: thank you, this package will work for me